# Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'

Tags: android, android-espresso, robotium, ui-testing, android-instrumentation

I've started working with `Espresso` UI tests. I prepare custom `MockTestRunner`, `MockApplication` for initialization `Dagger` components and I've defined mock modules too. It looks like that:

```
public class MockTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.newApplication(cl, MockMyApplication.class.getName(), context);
    } }
```

`MyApp` is extended by

```
public class MockQrApplication extends MyApp {
    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    protected void initComponent() {
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();

        component = DaggerMyAppComponent
                .builder()
                .myAppModule(new MyAppModule(this))
                .busModule(new BusModule())
                .apiModule(new MockApiModule(mockWebServer))
                .facebookModule(new FacebookModule())
                .dataManagerModule(new DataManagerModule())
                .greenDaoModule(new GreenDaoModule())
                .trackModule(new TrackModule(this))
                .build();

        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

I added `testInstrumentationRunner` into `gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        ....
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "a.b.c.MockTestRunner"
    }
```

I want run login tests in my `LoginActivity`

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginActivityTest {
    protected Solo solo;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initVariables();
    }

    protected void initVariables() {
        solo = new Solo(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(), activityTestRule.getActivity());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLayout() {
        solo.waitForFragmentByTag(LoginFragment.TAG, 1000);

        onView(withId(R.id.email_input)).perform(clearText(), typeText("developer@appppp.com"));
        onView(withId(R.id.pass_input)).perform(clearText(), typeText("qqqqqqqq"));
        onView(withId(R.id.login_button)).perform(click());

        solo.waitForDialogToOpen();
    }
}
```

When I want to run my tests I got:

```
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'
Empty test suite.
```

[Edit]

This is `MockApiModule` which extends `ApiModule` class

```
public class MockApiModule extends ApiModule {
    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    public MockApiModule(MockWebServer mockWebServer) {
        this.mockWebServer = mockWebServer;
    }

    @Override
    public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(DataManager dataManager) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))       // throw NetworkOnMainThreadException
                .addConverterFactory(NullOnEmptyConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }

    @Override
    public ApiService provideApiService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ApiClient provideApiManager(Application application, ApiService apiService, DataManager dataManager) {
        return new MockApiClient(application, apiService, dataManager, mockWebServer);
    }
}
```

API login request looks like that:

```
apiService.postLoginUser(userLoginModel).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = null;
                    try {
                        loginResponse = gson.fromJson(MockResponse.getResourceAsString(this, "login.json"), LoginResponse.class);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    callback.onLoginSuccess(loginResponse);
                } else {
                    callback.onLoginFail(response.errorBody().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                callback.onLoginFail(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

It works if I change `MockMyApplication` into `MyApp` class of application in `MockTestRunner`

I get stracktrace

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1285)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:305)
at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.start(MockWebServer.java:303)
at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.start(MockWebServer.java:293)
at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.maybeStart(MockWebServer.java:143)
at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.getHostName(MockWebServer.java:172)
at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.url(MockWebServer.java:198)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.modules.MockApiModule.provideRetrofit(MockApiModule.java:38)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.modules.ApiModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(ApiModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:23)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.modules.ApiModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(ApiModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:9)
at dagger.internal.ScopedProvider.get(ScopedProvider.java:46)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.modules.ApiModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.get(ApiModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.java:23)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.modules.ApiModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.get(ApiModule_ProvideApiServiceFactory.java:9)
at dagger.internal.ScopedProvider.get(ScopedProvider.java:46)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.modules.ApiModule_ProvideApiManagerFactory.get(ApiModule_ProvideApiManagerFactory.java:31)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.modules.ApiModule_ProvideApiManagerFactory.get(ApiModule_ProvideApiManagerFactory.java:11)
at dagger.internal.ScopedProvider.get(ScopedProvider.java:46)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.activities.BaseActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(BaseActivity_MembersInjector.java:44)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.activities.BaseActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(BaseActivity_MembersInjector.java:13)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.components.DaggerQrContactsAppComponent.inject(DaggerQrContactsAppComponent.java:91)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.activities.BaseActivity.init(BaseActivity.java:74)
at com.mooduplabs.qrcontacts.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:64)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:532)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2511)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1375)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear , you are making a network call within the UI thread. As you are in instrumented test, there is a UI (main) thread and his behaviour is the same as when you launch app on real device. Show the code wich could contain network calls

Comment: Hey, Thx for your answer, I added `MockApiModule` and login request. I understand error message but I don't know reason. Because Test cannot start and I get that message

Comment: you cannot use your API login method inside the test thread. Is that function called somewhere during the setUp() method?

Comment: Nope, That method call only in `LoginActivity` and exactly in `FragmentLogin`. I didn't call API request in my tests. Take a look again tests. I create just new component which should be use into inject for `Activities` and `Fragments`.

Comment: It works if I change `MockMyApplication` into `MyApp` class of application in `MockTestRunner`

Comment: Ok I found that `mockWebServer.url("/")` make that error. But Why?

Comment: Got this problem recently. I tried the tutorial on this site, and it worked: https://medium.com/mindorks/instrumentation-testing-with-mockwebserver-and-dagger2-56778477f0cf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into similar issue, just avoid starting your activity right away during testing. You can achieve this by adjusting your test rule like the snippet below,

```
@Rule
// Do not launch the activity right away
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity.class, true, false);
```

and then starting the mock web server by yourself during test setup. It is basically happening because `mockWebServer.url("/")` tries to start the mock server for you in case it has not already started. You need to do it first if you don't want to do it later on during test execution (NetworkOnMainThreadException case).